# How and when to use SLEEP() correctly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sleep

In relation to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284162/calling-stored-procedure-sequentially-from-sql-file-and-php-fails-differently) today I am wondering how to use [MySQL's `SLEEP(duration)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) correctly.

From what I gathered reading MySQL Dev forums and very vague description in MySQL Docs I can't use it this way:

```
SELECT ...
SLEEP(1); /* wait for a second before another SELECT */
SELECT ...
```

So what is it good for then?

Comment: based on reading of the mysql docs, i would have tried it your way first, i never seem to walk away with useful information after reading the mysql docs, thanks to Konerak below for the very simple answer ....

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
SELECT SLEEP(5);
SELECT ...
```

But what are you using this for? Are you trying to circumvent/reinvent mutexes or transactions?

Comment: I use this command to confirm slow query logging is working as it should.

Comment: Should also be useful for testing asynchronous queries at the application layer.

Comment: @MicalM  There is no reason to reassign "accepted" answer.  This answer is also correct and was so for 5 years before I chimed in.  I just added that other one because I thought it added value to the question posed.

Comment: I use this command so the dump import won't start until after the script decompression finishes.  It kicked in some time while I was sleeping last night.

Answer (score 131):

If you don't want to `SELECT SLEEP(1);`, you can also `DO SLEEP(1);`  It's useful for those situations in procedures where you don't want to see output.

e.g.

```
SELECT ...
DO SLEEP(5);
SELECT ...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The output of `sleep` is always 0, Why would anyone bother selecting the output of `sleep` for.....

Comment: @Pacerier: this answer appeared 5 years later, but the example uses DO, which is indeed more elegant than SELECT. The big clue was showing SLEEP itself was not a command, but rather a function, which both answers show, but feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Pacerier one reason to select the output of sleep is to put it in a query to test locking and transaction isolation levels in concurrent queries, for example.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to see the output you can add a join or bogus nested query like: select 1 from (select sleep(1)) a;

Comment: @Pacerier Wrong. It can output `1`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep

Comment: As mentioned above `SELECT sleep(n)` returns `1` if it's interrupted. This output is particularly useful when testing timeouts. For eg. with `SET SESSION max_execution_time=<milliseconds>`