# procedure calling in for loop throwing exception

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I am getting exception while calling a stored procedure in a for loop.here is my code

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$total      = 0;
$error      = 0; 
$trimmed = explode("\n",file_get_contents($fileName));

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {    
    $qry_ins = "call sampleProcedureTest();";
     try {
         mysql_query($qry_ins) or throw_ex(mysql_error());
         $total++;
     } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo $e;
         echo  $qry_ins;
         echo "</br></br>";
         $error++;
     }
}
```

I have searched but didn't find any good reason and solution
**NOTE:** When I remove the loop then it works fine.But My need is to call in a loop

Guide me please regarding this

**EDIT # 1:** Here is the procedure

```
BEGIN
DECLARE uid VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "0000";
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 4) AS passwordStrin into uid FROM NO WHERE uid not in (Select ID from UIDLIST WHERE ID=uid);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO UIDLIST values(uid);

    select REPLACE(MSG,'URL',CONCAT('http://abc.org/?uid=',uid)) as message,SOURCE as sender,MODE as mode,uid  as uniqueid from testDB _MESSAGE;

    select REPLACE(MSG,'URL',CONCAT('http://abc.org/?uid=',uid)) as message,SOURCE as sender,MODE as mode,uid  as uniqueid from testDB_MESSAGE;
END
```

Comment: What's the exception you are getting? What's the stored procedure look like?

Comment: Add code of stored procedure here.

Comment: procedure added.please review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `select` statement from your procedure (in case they are not useful for you).The problem is that procedure is returning you data so thats why it is problematic when you call it from the same script in a loop
also see [Calling Stored Procedure in foreach loop - only first executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285837/calling-stored-procedure-in-foreach-loop-only-first-executed)
Another solution is (which is not recommended) in case you still want to place `select statments in procedure` that use need to connect to db , call procedure , release connection in every iteration.